# Function to remove special characters

Tags: vba

I need a function which completely deletes all special characters (visible/invisible) from a string besides A-Z, a-z, 0-9. I have already prepared a function, unfortunately I find out it's leaving commas ( , ) somehow, and maybe more I don't know. Could you please take a look and advise:

```
Function RemoveSpecialChars(Tekst As String) As String

        Dim a$, b$, c$, i As Integer
         
        a$ = Tekst
        For i = 1 To Len(a$)
            b$ = Mid(a$, i, 1)
            If b$ Like "[A-Z,a-z,0-9]" Then
                c$ = c$ & b$
            End If
        Next i
        
        RemoveSpecialChars = c$
        
End Function
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just remove the commas:

```
If b$ Like "[A-Za-z0-9]" Then
```

As it says [on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/swf8kaxw.aspx) for Visual Basic:

> To specify multiple ranges for the same character position, put them
>   within the same brackets without delimiters. For example, [A–CX–Z]
>   results in a match if the corresponding character position in string
>   contains any character within either the range A–C or the range X–Z.

Although MSDN doesn't specifically mention this for VBA, it shows the same behaviour.